# Query to Retrive Country,State,City and Location from a Table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Table Design**
[Only 1 Table ]
**id column name**

```
1   id   
2   name ={ Just a name of the country,state,city,location}  
3   mid ={ id of the upper hierarchy [Ex: if india id is 10 and its state inside that country mid is 10][if state id is 12 and city inside that state mid is 12]}  
4   parent tag ={Country,State,City,Location} [which is help to identify what is the column is [country or state or city or location]]]
```

but i have to get the value in a array in this format :

```
[[country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location][country,state,city,location]]
```

Every set of array should have a location , city which the location is in, state which the city is in,country  which the state is in

**Output Array Format:**

```
a[][] =[[country,state,city,location]
```

[country,state,city,location]...etc.,]

**Answer can be Anything:** 
1.Query or Sub query:[Preferred]
2.Any looping statement :

DB Design

[image: DB Design]

Output Format

[image: Output Format]

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c78ee58b5d6d9edae68daf53101a3e2

Answer (score 2):

Try `JOIN`

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `[` + COT.ParentDescription +','+ ST.ParentDescription +','+ CT.ParentDescription +','+ LT.ParentDescription + `]` AS AddressList
    FROM LocationTable LT JOIN CityTable CT ON LT.ParentID = CT.OLMID AND CT.ParnetTag = 'City'
    JOIN StateTable ST ON ST.OLMID = CT.ParentID AND ST.ParnetTag = 'State'
    JOIN CountryTable COT ON COT.OLMID = ST.ParentID AND ST.ParnetTag = 'Country'
    WHERE LT.ParentDescription = 'Gopalapuram' AND LT.IsActive = 1 AND ST.IsActive = 1 AND CT.IsActive = 1 AND COT.IsActive = 1
```

To get full result use `COALESCE`

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Str  = COALESCE(@Str   + ' ', '') + AddressList
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT `[` + COT.ParentDescription +','+ ST.ParentDescription +','+ CT.ParentDescription +','+ LT.ParentDescription + `]` AS AddressList
        FROM LocationTable LT JOIN CityTable CT ON LT.ParentID = CT.OLMID AND CT.ParnetTag = 'City'
        JOIN StateTable ST ON ST.OLMID = CT.ParentID AND ST.ParnetTag = 'State'
        JOIN CountryTable COT ON COT.OLMID = ST.ParentID AND ST.ParnetTag = 'Country'
        WHERE LT.IsActive = 1 AND ST.IsActive = 1 AND CT.IsActive = 1 AND COT.IsActive = 1
)X

SELECT @Str
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive CTE one could generate something like that.

An example (MS Sql Server 2017, because also using STRING_AGG):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE countrystatelocations (
>  Id int primary key,
>  Name nvarchar(42),
>  ParentId int,
>  Tag varchar(8),
>  foreign key (parentId) 
>   references countrystatelocations(Id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO countrystatelocations
> (Id, Name, ParentId, Tag) VALUES 
> (11, 'Country1', null, 'COUNTRY'),
> (12, 'State1', 11, 'state'),
> (13, 'City1', 12, 'city'),
> (14, 'Loc1', 13, 'loc'),
> (15, 'Loc2', 13, 'loc'),
> (16, 'State2', 11, 'state'),
> (17, 'City2', 16, 'city'),
> (18, 'Loc3', 17, 'loc')
> ```

> ```
> WITH RCTE AS
> (
>   SELECT 
>     country.id AS countryId
>   , state.id AS stateId
>   , city.id AS cityId
>   , 0 AS lvl
>   , city.id AS parentId
>   , city.parentId AS locationId
>   , country.name AS countryName
>   , state.name AS stateName
>   , city.name AS cityName
>   , city.name AS locationName
>   FROM countrystatelocations AS country
>   JOIN countrystatelocations AS state 
>     ON state.parentId = country.id
>    AND state.tag = 'state'
>   JOIN countrystatelocations AS city
>     ON city.parentId = state.id
>    AND city.tag = 'city'
>   WHERE country.tag = 'country'
>
>   UNION ALL
>   
>   SELECT 
>     r.countryId
>   , r.stateId
>   , r.cityId
>   , r.lvl + 1
>   , loc.id
>   , loc.parentId
>   , r.countryName
>   , r.stateName
>   , r.cityName
>   , loc.name
>   FROM RCTE r
>   JOIN countrystatelocations loc
>     ON loc.parentId = r.parentId
> )
> SELECT CONCAT(
>    '[', countryName,
>    ', ', stateName,
>    ', ', cityName,
>    ', [', STRING_AGG(locationName,', '),
>    ']]') AS citylocations
> FROM RCTE
> WHERE lvl > 0
> GROUP BY countryName, stateName, cityName
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | citylocations                           |
> | :-------------------------------------- |
> | [Country1, State1, City1, [Loc1, Loc2]] |
> | [Country1, State2, City2, [Loc3]]       |
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a01e44a79c36cb957719b875949ef02)*